# Как вставить ImageView поверх ListView в андроиде?

Tags: android

Как вставить ImageView поверх ListView в андроиде? У меня есть ListView почти на весь экран и мне нужно поставить картинку поверх ListView. Как это можно будет сделать?

Comment: разметку в студию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете попробовать так

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Cпасибо! Не особо понимал разницу RelariveLayout и LinearLayout, теперь разобрался!

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `FrameLayout` или `RelativeLayout` для того, чтобы разместить элементы друг над другом

Comment: спасибо, использовал RelativeLayout!